# Docker fails to start in EndeavourOS

Tags: docker, endeavouros

I’m installing docker for the first time in endeavour but I seem to be missing something:

```
 sudo systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xeu docker.service" for details.
vfbsilva@isengard ~ $ systemctl status docker.service
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-03-27 14:34:46 -03; 2s ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 98650 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.soc>
   Main PID: 98650 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 64ms

mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at >
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
vfbsilva@isengard ~ $ journalctl -xeu docker.service
░░ Subject: A unidade docker.service falhou
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A unidade docker.service falhou.
░░ 
░░ O resultado é failed.
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at >
░░ Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ Automatic restarting of the unit docker.service has been scheduled, as the result for
░░ the configured Restart= setting for the unit.
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
░░ Subject: Unit failed
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ The unit docker.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
░░ Subject: A unidade docker.service falhou
░░ Defined-By: systemd
░░ Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
░░ 
░░ A unidade docker.service falhou.
░░ 
░░ O resultado é failed.
vfbsilva@isengard ~ $ systemctl status docker.service
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2024-03-27 14:34:46 -03; 3min 15s ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 98650 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.soc>
   Main PID: 98650 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
        CPU: 64ms

mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at >
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
mar 27 14:34:46 isengard systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Comment: That `journalctl` output is too verbose and I am concerned that some information is missing. Please replace it with the complete output of `journalctl -u docker` (or possibly something like `journalctl -u docker -n 100` if there is too much output).